# Error when using group_left in Prometheus

Tags: prometheus

Getting error when trying to use group_left between two queries

The query is:

```
floor(avg_over_time(dcgm_gpu_utilization{cluster_name="researchers"}[5m]) * on (instance) group_left(node) max by (node) (kube_node_labels{label_grid="true"}))
```

And it shows this error:

> Error executing query: found duplicate series for the match group {}
>   on the right hand-side of the operation: [{node="gpu-m-08"},
>   {node="gpu-l-03"}];many-to-many matching not allowed: matching labels
>   must be unique on one side

Query one output **floor(avg_over_time(dcgm_gpu_utilization{cluster_name="researchers"}[5m]))**:

```
{app="prometheus-node-exporter",chart="prometheus-node-exporter-1.3.0",cluster_name="researchers",gpu="0",heritage="Tiller",instance="172.21.4.101:9100",job="kubernetes-service-endpoints",kubernetes_name="prometheus-node-exporter",kubernetes_namespace="monitoring",release="prometheus-node-exporter",uuid="GPU-92e6ebf6-2b2d-c041-7f70-e16812c0ffa0"}
```

Query two output **max by (node) (kube_node_labels{label_grid="true"})**:

```
{node="gpu-m-08"}
{node="gpu-m-09"}
{node="gpu-m-12"}
```

I just want to see the node label in the problematic Query output.

BTW this works (without the label_grid=true label):

```
floor(avg_over_time(dcgm_gpu_utilization{cluster_name="researchers"}[5m])  * on (instance) group_left(nodename) node_uname_info)
```

It adds the nodename to the Query output labels list.

The main goal is to just see metrics with the label label_grid="true" and their node name.

Answer (score 5):

The RHS has no `instance` label, so it's trying to match all those series to one on the LHS. Try `max by (node, instance) (kube_node_labels{label_grid="true"})`

Comment: Thanks, for the answer.
Tried it but got this error:

**Error executing query: found duplicate series for the match group {instance=“10.42.18.31:8080”} on the right hand-side of the operation: [{instance=“10.42.18.31:8080", node=“gpu-m-13”}, {instance=“10.42.18.31:8080", node=“gpu-m-12”}];many-to-many matching not allowed: matching labels must be unique on one side**

Comment: You'll need to do something to chose only one of those nodes, maybe a `topk without (node)(1, kube_node_labels)`

Answer (score 1):

The `group_left()` modifier expects that the right-hand side of `*` operator (and any other operator) contains only a single time series per each `label=value` set specified inside `on()` modifier. Otherwise it returns `duplicate series for the match group` error. See [these docs](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/querying/operators/#many-to-one-and-one-to-many-vector-matches) for more details.

The solution is to specify the proper labels inside `on()` modifier, so every `label=value` set for these labels would have only a single time series on the right-hand side of `*` operator. The `instance` label is a good candidate to put inside `on()` modifier. The only issue is that the `dcgm_gpu_utilization` and `kube_node_labels` are collected from different targets with different TCP port numbers. So they have different `instance` label values (see [these docs](https://prometheus.io/docs/concepts/jobs_instances/) explaining how `instance` label is generated). This breaks [matching rules](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/querying/operators/#arithmetic-binary-operators) for `*` operator, so the following query returns nothing:

```
floor(avg_over_time(dcgm_gpu_utilization{cluster_name="researchers"}[5m]))
  * on (instance) group_left(node)
kube_node_labels{label_grid="true"}
```

This can be fixed by stripping the port number from `instance` label at both sides of `*` operator with the help of [label_replace](https://docs.victoriametrics.com/MetricsQL.html#label_replace) function:

```
label_replace(
  floor(avg_over_time(dcgm_gpu_utilization{cluster_name="researchers"}[5m])),
  "hostname",
  "$1",
  "instance",
  "([^:]+):.+"
)
  * on (hostname) group_left(node)
label_replace(
  kube_node_labels{label_grid="true"},
  "hostname",
  "$1",
  "instance",
  "([^:]+):.+"
)
```

This query extracts hostname part from `instance` labels, puts it into a `hostname` label and then joins the left-hand side and the right-hand side time series on this label.